# Jee webs services and angular : how can i print an html page, and change it before printing it

Tags: java, angularjs

I need to print an html page using jee web services or javascript. But how can i change it(add an image) before printing it?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to have css definitions that target your page for printing to simplify the styling and remove unwanted elements, or in your case add elements. Or just use jQuery to add the image

```
//Jquery solution
$("div.selector").html("").append("<img src..... />");

//CSS styles
<style tyle="text/css">
   <!--
   @media screen
   {
      p.bodyText {font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;}
   }

   @media print
   {
      p.bodyText {font-family:georgia, times, serif;}
   }
   @media screen, print
   {
      p.bodyText {font-size:10pt}
   }
   -->
</style>
```

Comment: But, should i add jquery library?, because i use angular library.and in the ".html(" ") , should i mention the html page that i should print?

Comment: Hi you don't have to add jquery lib, just use angular.element instead: angular.element("div.selector").html("").append("<img src..... />"); the html("") bit just clears the content of the element

Comment: Thank you johan. and this jquery code, should i put it in the html page?

Comment: No, this is an Angular app, right? then just put it in your controller for the page. a $scope.print_btn() function need to be added and bound to a button on the page.

Comment: Yeah, it's an angular app, it's because im new to angular .

Comment: so in this function $scope.print_btn() , i should call the window.print() ? If you can tell me about more details. Thank you so much

Comment: Oh , i think that i should add in that button: OnClick="javascript:window.print()" right?